# How to keep Android Studio working while downloading tools?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm currently working on Linux. I have a bad quality internet connection, so downloading large things could take a lot of time.

If I want to update / install new build tools to Android Studio a modal window is shown. So, for downloading, I'd have to wait for hours until it finishes. But, I need to keep coding while it downloads stuff.

Opening multiple instances of Android Studio didn't help.

I could run the SDK manager in a stand-alone way. But, I couldn't find a way to to upgrade the IDE version, or install tools like NDK in a non-blocking manner.

So, any idea?

Comment: Android Studio team added "Background" button to download tools in background. Its added to studio 2.2 but its still in preview mode.

Comment: To update IDE itself, no other way you have to wait until the update is done. I faced the same issue, so my suggestion is update the IDE regularly so you don't need to download bigger patch files.

Comment: new build tools/sdk can be downloaded in background using SDK manager that is directly in SDK directory. It also is accessible from AndroidStudio when you are in `Android SDK` settings screen -> there is a `Launch Standalone SDK Manager` link.

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses. Yes! they've added the "background" button, in the preview 2.2. I guess we'll need to wait them to release it in the official way, but we are closer.

Comment: Once I push the updates to background, how do I check what is its status ? I don't see any way of bringing it back to foreground

Comment: I am facing same problem

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing the same issue with the Android Studio 3.2 update, there doesn't seem to be any way to use the IDE while downloading the update, which is kind of stupid. I guess one solution is to download the entire IDE manually at [the Android Studio website](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads).

On a related note, when downloading emulator system images there is a URL displayed in the download window. You can simply copy'n'paste this in a browser to download it manually and then unpack in the correct `sdk/system-images/` folder if you want to download it "in the background".